# Discord.js bot trying to play mp3 file on voice channel - no error and also no sound

Tags: javascript, discord.js, playsound

My bot joins a voice channel, and then leaves and sends the message "Playing ok!", but does not play the mp3. I'm on Windows and I already checked that I could play the mp3 file with ffmpeg by command line. Does anyone know what's wrong?

```js
const path = require('path')

client.channels.fetch('Channel_ID').then(channel => {
     console.log(channel.name)
     console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'music.mp3'))
     channel.join().then((connection) => {
         const dispatcher = connection.play(path.join(__dirname, 'music.mp3'));
         dispatcher.on("speaking", speaking => {
             if (!speaking) {
               channel.leave()
               msg.channel.send("Playing ok!")
             }
        });         
   });
});
```

**Update:**
I changed the 'speaking' for the 'finish' event, and also tried the audio file in the comments. Now, the bot joins to the voice channel, stays the same time of the duration of mp3, and then leave the voice channel, but no sound yet.

**Update 2:**
I added ffmpeg to my PATH now. The bot showed a green circle like its playing something, but no sound again. Just in case, I put my bot under Admin permission, but also it was not enough.

Thanks for the help.

<sub>Using discord.js `v12.5.3`.</sub>

Comment: Copy-pasted your code, changed filename and channel id, works fine. Did you try different .mp3 files? I am using discord.js v12.5.3. [Here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/587327745961230339/876137798963458138/test.mp3) is a link to the audio file I tested it with.

Comment: Also your message "Playing ok!" is wrong, it means that the bot is **not** speaking... See above you have `if (!speaking) { ... }`. So when you get this message after the bot joined the voice channel, something is wrong, because the `StreamDispatcher` ended right away.

Comment: To debug this, take a look at the [`error`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/StreamDispatcher?scrollTo=e-error) event of `StreamDispatcher`.

Comment: @SkulaurunMrusal, thank very much for you comments. I changed the 'speaking' for the 'finish' event, and also tried with the audio file you sent a link. Now, the bot joins to the voice channel, stays the same time of the duration of mp3, and then leave the voice channel, but no sound yet. I'm also using discord.js v12.5.3. Are you playing on Windows? Maybe could be a problem with my ffmpeg.

Comment: I am also on windows. Oh I had ffmpeg in my PATH, that's why it worked without me installing anything. You can try `npm install ffmpeg-static`. Version of ffmpeg I have installed locally (the one in PATH) [here](https://i.imgur.com/LyL2iw2.png).

Comment: I added ffmpeg in my PATH now. The bot showed a green circle like its playing something, but no sound again. Just in case, I put my bot under Admin permission, but also it was not enough. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Hey @SkulaurunMrusal, now it works!!! I didn't have restart my pc after add ffmpeg to the PATH. Now I've restarted, that is gone!! Thank you very much for the attention and to save my bot!!! All the best!!

Comment: Glad to hear that! I will write an answer to the question then, for someone else that might encounter a similar issue.

Comment: I have written an answer, consider marking it as accepted. Also I have suggested an edit to your question with the info from comments. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Sure! I just accepted your answer.  Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For discord.js voice to work, you need to have following packages installed (as stated in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/general/welcome) under the installation section): either [`@discordjs/opus`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/opus) or [`opusscript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opusscript).

```
npm install @discordjs/opus
```

Also discord.js depends on `prism-media` and you should have ffmpeg installed for this to work properly.

```
npm install ffmpeg-static
```

If you don't want to install ffmpeg as a npm package and you already have ffmpeg installed, make sure to add it to the `PATH` environmental variable and restart your working environment.

The OP said, that restarting his computer after adding ffmpeg to the `PATH` worked.

Rest of the info from comments:

> Also your message "Playing ok!" is wrong, it means that the bot is **not** speaking... See above you have `if (!speaking) { ... }`. So when you get this message after the bot joined the voice channel, something is wrong, because the `StreamDispatcher` ended right away.

> To debug this, take a look at the [`error`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/StreamDispatcher?scrollTo=e-error) event of `StreamDispatcher`.